# How can Arduino save data from PHP Script?

Tags: php, arduino, arduino-uno

I created a PHP script so I could retrive data from my online database(MySQL) but I not being able to pass that information to my arduino+Ethernet Shield(using Ethercard.h).

I all want is to get everything that my PHP script retrived as a vector of strings.

Example of what my PHP script returns:

```
ABCDF
GHYEJ
JDYDI
HSTSU
PIFYF
```

I want it to become this in my Arduino:

```
char* test = {"ABCDF", "GHYEJ". "JDYDI", "HSTSU", "PIFYF" };
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Edit:
So, I'm trying @frarugi87 solution but I'm getting DNS Failed. Here is the code I'm using:

```
#include <enc28j60.h>
#include <EtherCard.h>
#include <net.h>

#define HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET 0

/* Setup for Ethernet Library */
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 };
static byte myip[] = {192,168,1,58};
static byte gatewayip[] = {192,168,1,1};
static byte dnsip[] = {8,8,8,8}; //Google DNS
const char website[] PROGMEM = "http://arksecurity.net16.net";

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
static uint32_t timer = 0;

static void response_callback (byte status, word off, word len){
  Serial.print((const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET);  
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 8) == 0)
    Serial.println("Failed to access Ethernet controller");
  else
    Serial.println("Ethernet controller initialized");
    ether.staticSetup(myip, gatewayip, dnsip);

  if(!ether.dnsLookup(website)){
    Serial.println("DNS failed");  
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("DNS resolution done");

    ether.printIp("SRV IP:\t", ether.hisip);
  Serial.println();
}
void loop() {
  word pos = ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() > timer){
    timer = millis() + 5000;
    ether.browseUrl("/", "test.php", website, response_callback);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit2: Alright I got it running. The DNS problem was caused by my Router so I had to set it to 192.168.1.1 and I also had to make some tweaks on ether.browseUrl because it was also returning error. 
This is what my code looks like now:

```
#include <enc28j60.h>
#include <EtherCard.h>
#include <net.h>

#define HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET 50

/* Setup for Ethernet Library */
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 };
static byte myip[] = {192,168,1,58};
static byte gatewayip[] = {192,168,1,1};
static byte dnsip[] = {192,168,1,1}; //Google DNS
const char website[] PROGMEM = "www.arksecurity.net16.net";

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
static uint32_t timer = 0;

static void response_callback (byte status, word off, word len){
  Serial.print((const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET);  
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 8) == 0)
    Serial.println("Failed to access Ethernet controller");
  else
    Serial.println("Ethernet controller initialized");
    ether.staticSetup(myip, gatewayip, dnsip);

  if(!ether.dnsLookup(website)){
    Serial.println("DNS failed");  
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("DNS resolution done");

    ether.printIp("SRV IP:\t", ether.hisip);
  Serial.println();
}
void loop() {
  word pos = ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() > timer){
    timer = millis() + 5000;
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/test."),"php", website, response_callback);
    }
}
```

Now I have to save the data I get into a char* []. Any ideas?

Edit3:

So this is how my code is looking so far. The thing is, on the last comparison I make "for(int i=0; i < 20 - 1; i++)" I get all "Wrong" for like the first two responsecallback and after that it starts to get one "OK" like it should. Is it expected?

After that, I would like to make it call the response_callback just once a day, like at midnight. Is it possible?

```
#define HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET 163
#define MAX_STRINGS 20
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 8
#define REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS 5000

/* Setup for Ethernet Library */
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 };
const char website[] PROGMEM = "www.arksecurity.net16.net"; 
const char device[] = "0001"; 
char test[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
String test2 = "1234";
char * comp[20];
uint8_t receivedResponse;
unsigned long timer;

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];

static void response_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {

    int i_string = 0;
    int i_char = 0;
    int i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET;
    char carat;
    for (i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET; (carat =(char)Ethernet::buffer[i_ethBuff]) != 0; i_ethBuff++)
    {
        if (carat == '\n')
        { // New line char = new string
            if (i_string < MAX_STRINGS - 1){
                i_string++;
                i_char = 0;
                }
            else
                break; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (i_char < MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
            {
                test[i_string][i_char] = carat;
                i_char++;
            } // otherwise discard the char (max length of string reached)
        }
    }
  receivedResponse = 1;
}
void setup() {
  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 8) == 0)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to access Ethernet controller");
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Ethernet controller initialized");
  Serial.println();

  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to get configuration from DHCP");
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("DHCP configuration done");

  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
  {
    Serial.println("DNS failed");
    while(1);
  }
  else 
    Serial.println("DNS resolution done"); 

  ether.printIp("SRV IP:\t", ether.hisip);
  Serial.println();
  timer = millis() - REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS;
}

void loop() {    
  word pos = ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() - timer > REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS){
    timer += REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS;
    receivedResponse = 0;
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/DevicesQuery.php?device="),device , website, response_callback);

while (!receivedResponse);
for(int i=0; i < 20 - 1; i++){
      comp[i] = test[i];
      if(test2.equals(comp[i])){
      Serial.println("OK");
        }
        else
        Serial.println("Wrong");
       } 

    }

}
```

Edit4: Made it work with another comparison. I want it to catch data every 5s until he receives anything and them make it wait for a long time. The problem is that when I make timer2 = 500000; it actually make it catch data even faster. Why is that?

```
#include <enc28j60.h>
#include <EtherCard.h>
#include <net.h>

#define HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET 163
#define MAX_STRINGS 10
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20
#define REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS 5000


/* Setup for Ethernet Library */
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74, 0x69, 0x69, 0x2D, 0x30, 0x31 };
const char website[] PROGMEM = "www.arksecurity.net16.net"; //link para o banco de dados do usuário em questão
const char device[] = "0001"; // adicionar aqui o número do dispositivo equivalente ao que aparece no Bando de Dados
char test[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];
String test2 = "9999";
//uint8_t receivedResponse;
unsigned long timer;
unsigned long timer2 = 5000;

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];

static void response_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_STRINGS;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<=MAX_STRING_LENGTH;j++)
            test[i][j] = 0;

    int i_string = 0;
    int i_char = 0;
    int i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET;
    char carat;
    for (i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET; (carat = (char)Ethernet::buffer[i_ethBuff]) != 0; i_ethBuff++)
    {
        if (carat == '\n')
        { // New line char = new string
            if (i_string < MAX_STRINGS - 1){
                i_string++;
                i_char = 0;
                }
            else
                break; // Limite de memória do Arduino
        }
        else
        {
            if (i_char < MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
            {
                test[i_string][i_char] = carat;
                i_char++;
            } // otherwise discard the char (max length of string reached)
        }
    }
  //receivedResponse[0] = 1;
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 53) == 0)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to access Ethernet controller");
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Ethernet controller initialized");
  Serial.println();

  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to get configuration from DHCP");
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("DHCP configuration done");

  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
  {
    Serial.println("DNS failed");
    while(1);
  }
  else 
    Serial.println("DNS resolution done"); 

  ether.printIp("SRV IP:\t", ether.hisip);
  Serial.println();

  timer = millis() - timer2;
}

void loop() {

  word pos = ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() - timer > timer2)
  {
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/DevicesQuery.php?device="),device , website, response_callback);

    if(test[0][0] != 0){
    Serial.println("Data Received");
    Serial.println(test[0]);
    Serial.println(test[1]);
    Serial.println(test[2]);
    Serial.println(test[3]);
    Serial.println(test[4]);
    Serial.println(test[5]);
    timer2 = 500000;
    }
    else{
      Serial.println("Nothing");
      timer2 = 5000;
     }
    timer += timer2;
}
```

Edit5: I added this part to my code so i could also send data to my server but I'm for some reason only one data is being sent even tough I'm using a loop for it. Why is this happening?

The code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < countRegister ; i++)
{
   register[i].toCharArray(tempRegister, 80);
   ether.browserUrl(PTSR("/log.php"), tempRegister , browser_callback);
}


static void browser_callback (byte status, word off, word len)
{
 Serial.println("Data sent");
}
```

Comment: so your arduino is doing an http request to wherever your php script is?

Comment: I don't even know how to request the http with this EtherCard.h
I'm new to Arduino and all examples I find is based on Ethernet.h

I already connected it to the internet, I pinged and I could use it as a WebServer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, all of this is NOT TESTED AT ALL. I'm still waiting for my board to arrive, so... I'm using a great set of tutorials I found on the internet (they are in Italian language, however). Particularly [here](http://www.lucadentella.it/2012/02/19/enc28j60-e-arduino-3/) is the tutorial on how to get data from a server.

Ok, first you have to setup the ENC28J60 board with all the required parameters, such as the MAC address and the IP configuration. In the example I used DHCP, but you can use a static configuration (hope you know how to do that).

Then you have to check if you can resolve the name of the website (DNS query) - not sure if this is really necessary).

Then just poll the website (in this example every 5 seconds) and analyze the packet.

Here is the code:

```
#include <EtherCard.h>

#define HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET 0
static byte mymac[] = {0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x90,0xAB};
char website[] PROGMEM = "www.yourwebsite.com";

byte Ethernet::buffer[700];
static uint32_t timer = 0;

static void response_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
  Serial.print((const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET);
} 

void setup () {
  Serial.begin(57600);

  if (!ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 10))
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to access Ethernet controller");
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Ethernet controller initialized");
  Serial.println();

  if (!ether.dhcpSetup())
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to get configuration from DHCP");
    while(1);
  }
  else
    Serial.println("DHCP configuration done");

  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website))
  {
    Serial.println("DNS failed");
    while(1);
  }
  else 
    Serial.println("DNS resolution done"); 

  ether.printIp("SRV IP:\t", ether.hisip);
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());

  if (millis() > timer) {
    timer = millis() + 5000;
    ether.browseUrl("/", "yourpage.php", website, response_callback);
  }
}
```

The output of this sketch, on the serial console, will be something like this (picture taken from the tutorial I mentioned earlier)

[image: Http header]

As you can see there is a header before the actual page. You just have to count how many chars they are and put this value in HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET.

Another method, if this header varies, is to add something before the current message (for instance wrap everything in a `<body>` tag) and search for it.

In any case, in the `response_callback` function you will have all of your data in `Ethernet::buffer + off + header_offset`. Then you have to parse it and put it into an array, but I hope you can do it by yourself..

EDIT:

To use a static IP you will have to set it this way:

```
static byte myip[] = {192,168,1,10};
static byte gatewayip[] = {192,168,1,1};
//static byte dnsip[] = {8,8,8,8}; // Google DNS; change if you want to use another
static byte dnsip[] = {192,168,1,1}; // The OP said that with google dns something was not working
...
ether.staticSetup(myip, gatewayip, dnsip);
```

EDIT2:

Well, since you already have the data as a string, it's really easy to split it into chunks. One possible solution:

```
#define MAX_STRINGS 10
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 10

char test[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];

static void response_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_STRINGS;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<=MAX_STRING_LENGTH;j++)
            test[i][j] = 0;

    int i_string = 0;
    int i_char = 0;
    int i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET;
    char carat;
    for (i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET; (carat = (char)Ethernet::buffer[i_ethBuff]) != 0; i_ethBuff++)
    {
        if (carat == '\n')
        { // New line char = new string
            if (i_string < MAX_STRINGS-1)
                i_string++;
            else
                break; // Too many strings; discarding all the other ones
        }
        else
        {
            if (i_char < MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
            {
                test[i_string][i_char] = carat;
                i_char++;
            } // otherwise discard the char (max length of string reached
        }
    }
}
```

If one of the lengths is less than 255 then you can change the int counter to a uint8_t.

EDIT3:

To detect strings as separators, it's a bit trickier. For instance, to detect `"<br>"`, you can:

```
char separator[] = "<br>";

for (i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET; (carat = (char)Ethernet::buffer[i_ethBuff]) != 0; i_ethBuff++)
{
    if (i_char < MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
    {
        test[i_string][i_char] = carat;
        i_char++;

        uint8_t stringDetected = 0;
        if (i_char >= sizeof(separator))
        {
            int i_sep;
            stringDetected = 1;
            for (i_sep = 0; i_sep < sizeof(separator) && (stringDetected); i_sep++)
            { // You can try to detect it
                if (test[i_string][i_char - sizeof(separator) + i_sep] != separator[i_sep]);
                    stringDetected = 0;
            }
        }

        if (stringDetected)
        {
            test[i_string][i_char - sizeof(separator)] = '\0';
            if (i_string < MAX_STRINGS-1)
                i_string++;
            else
                break; // Too many strings; discarding all the other ones
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this works (maybe you have to correct the counters by +/-1 (don't know if sizeof will return the trailing \0).

Just remember to increase the space for the single strings (they will need to store the separator too)

EDIT 4:

As for the wrong test, I think it is because you haven't received yet the response. You can wait for the response to come back before testing.

Moreover, I noticed a small bug in the timer: you have to make it unsigned long and to test for millis() - timer instead of millis() > timer, otherwise you will have problems at timer rollover. I fixed it in this code:

```
// Before the setup
#define REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS 5000
uint8_t receivedResponse;
unsigned long timer;

// At the end of setup
timer = millis() - REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS;

// Inside response callback
for (i_ethBuff = off + HTTP_HEADER_OFFSET; (carat = (char)Ethernet::buffer[i_ethBuff]) != 0; i_ethBuff++)
{
    ...
}
receivedResponse = 1;

// In the main loop
if (millis() - timer > REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS)
{
    timer += REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS;
    receivedResponse = 0;
    ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/DevicesQuery.php?device="),device , website, response_callback);

    while (!receivedResponse);
    for(int i=0; i < 20 - 1; i++)
    {
        comp[i] = test[i];
        if(test2.equals(comp[i]))
            Serial.println("OK");
        else
            Serial.println("Wrong");
    }
}
```

As for executing it once a day, if you want to execute it exactly at midnight you will need some way to track the time (e.g. an RTC or using the NTP protocol with the ethernet). It is not really trivial, but you can find lots of examples on how to use an RTC.

If, on the other hand, you want to execute it just once per day (regardless of the time) just change the define `REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS` to the correct value (24h = 1440 min = 86400s = 86400000ms, so `#define REQUEST_EVERY_X_MS 86400000`) and it should run at the moment when you turn it on and then every 24 hours. You can use periods up to 4294967294 ms, or roughly 49 days.

EDIT 5:

Ok, looking at the thoughts of other people (mainly from the link provided by the OP in the comments below) it looks that

1. browseUrl does not like to be called twice before finishing the previous time
2. callbacks do not live in interrupts, but in main code. Consequently you can't block the program.

So.. Try implementing this for subsequent calls:

```
volatile uint8_t receivedResponse;

// in the main
for(int i = 0; i < countRegister ; i++)
{
    register[i].toCharArray(tempRegister, 80);
    receivedResponse = 0;
    ether.browserUrl(PTSR("/log.php"), tempRegister , browser_callback);
    while (!receivedResponse)
        ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());
}

// the callback
static void browser_callback (byte status, word off, word len)
{
    Serial.println("Data sent");
    receivedResponse = 1;
}
```

Hope this solves all the problems ;)

Comment: Thx for the response. I'm trying it now but I'm getting DNS failed.

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso did you write your website in the `char website[]` variable? Is it connected to the internet? How did you ping (you said you managed to ping something)

Comment: Yes I did. Altough I had to add const to make it work(const char website[]) but I don't think this is the problem.
I'm using an static IP and when I connected my arduino to my router, I was able to ping it from my pc to make sure it was working properly.

Comment: ok, so you are using a static IP. did you write the DNS when you configured it? Check the answer to see how..

Comment: No I did not. Gonna try that again later when I leave work.
Thx again for the help!

Comment: Still nothing. Just edited my post with the actual code I'm using.

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso Added the reading part; if it suits your need then mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Hello again. Just tried your code but I think i didn't work. Nothing was showed on the terminal even when I tried to use Serial.println (test[x][x]).
Here is a photo I took to show the result I was getting with the previous code I showed: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=464459EFD9DEA5DD!1513&authkey=!ADJEbga1uGBDV00&v=3&ithint=photo%2cjpg

Btw, using this as a global variable won't kill the arduino memory pretty fast?
Ps.: Sorry that it is an actual photo and not a ss but I was using my mother laptop and her printscreen button wasn't working.

Comment: As you can see you are not receiving "NUMBER newline NUMBER newline" from the PHP, but "NUMBER <br> NUMBER <br>". So the separator is "<br>" and not '\n'. Now, you have two solutions: 1) change my code to detect a string instead of a single character 2) change the php script so that instead of sending NUMBER<br> it sends NUMBER\n. Solution 2 is much easier if you have access to the source code of your page

Comment: It worked! Thx a lot! I changed my php source code to use "\n" insted of "<BR>" and it worked like charm.
I'm gonna mark your answer as accepted but if you don't mind, how can I do the same thing but detecting a string instead of a single character?
I don't know if it helps but all string I want to retrieve will have the same number of characters.
Thx a lot again!

Comment: You are welcome ;) And.. The string recognition is implemented in the third edit.. Iù hope :P

Comment: Thx again for the big help! Just one more thing ( I promise lol), why test[][] returns nothing if I try to use Serial.println outside this loop:


if (i_char < MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
            {
                test[i_string][i_char] = carat;
                i_char++;
            }

Comment: Well, test should KEEP the data you write in. How are you printing the data? And are you sure you received some data?

Comment: yeah, I'm sure. I also thought it was weird because it's a global variable. I'm using Serialprintln();
If, for example, I add Serialprintln(test[i_string][i_char]) inside the "if (i_char < MAX_STRING_LENGTH)" loop it works great, but if I try to do the something like Serialprintln(test[i_string][1]) inside "if (carat == '\n')" it return me nothing

Comment: If you want to print the whole string you can use `Serial.println(test[i_string]);`. Anyway you should use this BEFORE incrementing the i_string variable. And IMPORTANT: I noticed I made a mistake in the code: you should test for MAXSTRING-1 before incrementing i_string instead of MAXSTRING, otherwise you will overflow. So please correct it in your code if you used it..

Comment: It's all good now. I was already using before incrementing the i_string. The problem was on the MAXSTRING itself. Don't know how I didn't noticed that.

Thx again!

Comment: Sorry to bother once again, I edited my post one more time with my actual code. I think the response_callback is not returning anything on the first couple of times. Is it expected?

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso this is becoming the most edited question on SO :P anyway I've updated the answer with a piece of code and some info, and a bug fix

Comment: it problably already is haha. 
The new timer is working great and better than before but for some reason the "receivedResponse" is always 0

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso did you put the `receivedResponse = 1;` in the response callback after the for loop?

Comment: yes. I added the changes to Edit 3. If I comment the While and use a Serial.println(receivedResponse) it always returns 0. I also tried to add the receivedResponse = 1 before the break but didn't workout either

Comment: You placed `while (!receivedResponse);` in the wrong place, if the code you uploaded in the answer is yours. You should wait for it AFTER the call to browseUrl and before the for, not before the if for the millis

Comment: Actually, I edited the post by hand because I wasn't home. On my actual code the while is after the call and before the for.

Comment: Wait... Try declaring the variable as volatile. Instead of writing `uint8_t receivedResponse;` write `volatile uint8_t receivedResponse;`. Then report back..

Comment: using it as volatile didn't  work also. Even if I try to use "receivedResponse = 1;" inside "if (i_string < MAX_STRINGS - 1)" it always returns 0

Comment: with volatile it should have worked.. I don't know why it doesn't.. But... Why should it fail? Anyway you should write `timer += timer2;` BEFORE changing `timer2`, not after..

Comment: Once again thx a lot for you help. Gonna try to figure out now the rest I plan to do so I don't bother you again haha.
Really really grateful :)

Comment: It's me again... I'm trying to send data to my server multiple times now(edit5 on the post) but for some reason it only sends one even tough i'm using a for loop. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try using a delay between browseUrl calls. If it doesn't work, try debugging it with the serial interface (for instance, print the `tempRegister` value before sending it, or check if you get multiple data on the server even if you just get one data sent notification

Comment: Already did this and tempRegister is working fine. Also tried to add delay and still didn't work and I never got multiple variables on the server. I think maybe it's taking too long to sent the data or it just fails something and doesn't send at all.

Comment: Do you receive the first, the last or a random value?

Comment: Usually the last one but sometimes none at all

Comment: And if you put the count value to 1 (i.e. just send the first one) does it do something weird?

Comment: Then try to put a delay(2000) before calling the function. Then remove it, try setting your count to 1 and to reduce the "loop" time (i.e. the interval between two requests) to less than 2 seconds. Report back with he results of these two tests

Comment: I already tried to put a delay between them and I can say it only showed once the "Data Sent" but I actually can't confirm if it sent all the data or just the last one to my server. When I get home from work I will test it and post here.
I also tried to add a sentOK = 1 after the Serial.println("Data sent") inside de ether.browseurl  and use the while(!sentOK); loop before sending another request but it got locked inside the loop forever even tough i later removed the loop and used a Serial.println(sentOK) and it returned 1 like expected.

Comment: I tried with counter = 1 without delay and it worked great. Added delay(5000) with counter = 2 and didn't send any of them. Tried another 2 times without delay and counter = 2 and it sent both data first time and the second time it sent nothing. With counter = 1 it works fine but anything greater than that is just luck.

Comment: then try to add `ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());` after the `browseUrl` function, so you call it before trying to send another request

Comment: it looks like it is responding faster now when my counter is only one but anything higher than that keep getting the same error

Comment: and putting a 5000ms delay after the packetloop? and before?

Comment: If I add delay before or after it doesn't send any data at all. Even with countRegister = 1

Comment: Edit 5 is out ;) hope that now everything will work ;)

Comment: Good to know. So the reason why edit 4 was not working is this: you can't just wait for the flag, you have to call those functions repeatedly.. Thank you for giving me the possibility to learn this :)

Comment: Glad that many questions wasn't just a wast of time for you. Once again, thx a lot for all the help!

Comment: Sorry to bring this topic back, but do you know what can I do if I use xampp with local MySQL database instead of the online one? I tried to change the website to 192.168.1.1 and other things but didn't work. 

Btw, I already have xampp up and running

Comment: Hey @ViníciusAffonso I missed you :P Anyway, usually remote servers are more troublesome because of firewalls and so on. If you correctly configured everything, then it should work out of the box. Now, I'm not much into xampp, but be sure to 1) start the MySQL service (using the xampp control panel, if I remember correctly) and 2) to correctly setup the MySQL port . For instance, if you set the MySQL port to 12345, then you will have to connect to 192.168.1.1:12345

Comment: hahaha, good hear that! I'm sure it is supposed to be really simple but I think I might be missing something. I already have MYSQL up and running I already created the same databases I sued online but since I will not have an actually connection open, I won't be able to get a dhcp or DNS right? I will also have to set a gateway in manually or I won't be necessary?

Comment: I think I already know what the problem is. I'm supposed to still connect my Arduino to my router syndrome there access the local database on my computer. The problem is that I want to connect my arduino Ethernet direct to my computer and have access to the db without the need of an Internet connection. Is it possible?

Comment: @ViníciusAffonso Sure, as long as you configure static IPs on both arduino and PC.. Or at least I think so...

Comment: I thought that in this case it would probably work i I used something like 127.0.0.1

Comment: Where did you put it? android, php code, javascript code, ...?

Comment: I already change my php to work with xampp and it's working fine. The problem I'm facing it only with Arduino trying to communicate with it too. I'm changing static ip, gatewayip, etc

Comment: And what if you use another pc?

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I just don't know if I'm using the right IP on the right fields or if I'm supposed to use another kind of setup

Comment: No, I mean, try using another PC to connect to your PC. If the problem is the arduino, the new PC will be able to connect. If the problem is, as I suppose, with the xampp configuration then the second PC won't be able to access the data too.

Comment: Oh, I see. Gonna try that when I get home! @frarugi87

Comment: Can't reach it using another computer either :/

Comment: Alright, got it working with my computer by disabling the firewall of the computer hosting xampp but still no response from Arduino

Comment: Ok, so it was the firewall... Good. Now, you can use it from another pc but not from arduino, right? What is the problem? Does the arduino receive wrong messages?ù

Comment: It doesn't receive anything at all.

Comment: I think since I'm not using Internet I'm not exactly supposed to try retrieve it from callback. I probably have to open a TCP/IP connection instead but then I would have to change my entire code. Thinking in another direction, can I connect my arduino to the Internet trough my computer instead of Plugins it directly to the router?

Comment: Yes, usually on windows PC I find it easier to just enable connection sharing (search for ICS). Or make a bridge. But, before that, can you post your code? 'cause it's really really strange...

Comment: I was reading about that and gonna test when I get home. My code is still the same that we was discussing before. I only tried to change the dhcp for a static ip and gatewayip to see if it would work